# Copy and paste in the last empty row with condition

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to paste cell value or text from a column belonging to a table to last empty row in the same table but in a different column and in the same worksheet

Example:

If range F12 ('for all column F) <>"" then

Copy and paste text in the last empty row in column E

Same principle to apply to the entire column F

Many thanks for your kind reply

Code:

```
Public Sub CopyRows2()
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row   'find the last row of data
    For x = 2 To FinalRow                           'loop trough each row
        thisValue = Cells(x, 9).Value               'Decide to copy based on column I
        If thisValue <> "" Then
            Cells(x, 9).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet6").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 5).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Sheet6").Select
        Else
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Public Sub CopyRows()
Sheets("Sheet6").Select
'find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.count, 5).End(xlUp).row
'loop trough each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    'Decide to copy based on column I
    thisValue = Cells(x, 9).Value
    If thisValue <> "" Then
    Cells(x, 9).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.count, 5).End(xlUp).row + 1
    Cells(NextRow, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    Else
    End If
Next x
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This will copy all non-empty values from column F, at the end of column E (starting at first empty cell)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()

    Const MAIN_SHEET    As String = "Sheet6"    '<- Update Sheet Name
    Const FROM_COL      As String = "F"         '<- Copy from this columns
    Const TO_COL        As String = "E"         '<- Copy to this column

    Dim lrFrom As Long, lrTo As Long, i As Long, val As String

    With Sheets(MAIN_SHEET)

        lrFrom = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FROM_COL).End(xlUp).Row    'last row in FROM col

        lrTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TO_COL).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'first empty row in TO

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False                      'turn off screen updating
        For i = 2 To lrFrom                                     'loop all values in FROM
            val = .Cells(i, FROM_COL).Value2
            If Len(val) > 0 Then                                'if not empty
                .Cells(lrTo, TO_COL).Value2 = val               'copy in TO col
                lrTo = lrTo + 1                                 'next cell in TO col
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True                       'turn on screen updating
    End With
End Sub
```

---

To copy only the last non-empty cell from F into the first empty cell in E

```
Public Sub CopyRow()

    Const MAIN_SHEET    As String = "Sheet6"    '<- Update Sheet Name
    Const FROM_COL      As String = "F"         '<- Copy from this columns
    Const TO_COL        As String = "E"         '<- Copy to this column

    Dim lrFrom As Long, lrTo As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets(MAIN_SHEET)
        lrFrom = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FROM_COL).End(xlUp).Row    'last row in FROM col
        lrTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TO_COL).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'first empty row in TO

        .Cells(lrTo, TO_COL).Value2 = .Cells(lrFrom, FROM_COL).Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

---